# Visual Studio Team Services : Getting error while loading the Widget

Tags: widget

I am trying to extract the work items of my project using the VSTS Rest API for work item tracking but getting below error while loading the widget in visual studio team services.

> message : "HostAuthorizationNotFound"
>   name: "TFS.WebApi.Exception"
>   responseText:""$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"HostAuthorizationNotFound","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DelegatedAuthorization.SessionTokenCreateException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi","typeKey":"SessionTokenCreateException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}"

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error writing my own custom VSTS extension. To resolve the issue, I had to explicitly uninstall and reinstall the extension.